# Special characters been counted as words

Tags: jquery

I have the following Word count code I am working on and I want to prevent it from counting special xters like ^%$£()* as words:

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("#sys-tbox").each(function() {
        var input = '#' + this.id;
        counter(input);
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            counter(input);
        });
    });
});

function counter(field) {
    var number = 0;
    var text = $(field).val();
    var word = $(field).val().split(/[ \n\r]/);
    words = word.filter(function(word) {
        return word.length > 0
    }).length;
        $('.words').text(words);
        $('.character').text(text.length);
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKKY6/1/)

If it's already been answered, please provide me with the links.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition inside your word filter that ensures there is at least a number or a letter in there:

```
words = word.filter(function(word) {
    return word.length > 0 && word.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9]/);
}).length;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/tKKY6/3/)

Comment: Just one more question @oGeez, if I want to add just a checkbox so that when checked, it automatically calculates the number of paragraphs. What feasible is that. Sorry still new to programming

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover This is same as my code and how did you confirm this? You said, mine is not working

Comment: Guys please cheek in mind that this will cause isseues with unicode characters like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover I'd be glad to help you, but please have a go yourself and then come back and ask another question if you have trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code;

```
words = word.filter(function(word) {
        var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_']*$/;
        if (pattern.test(word)) {
            return word.length > 0
        }
    }).length;
```

I assume you want only alphanumeric characters.

You can see working demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/tKKY6/4/**

**Edit:** You can update `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_']*$/` according to your need

Comment: Nop not working. When I type words like *There're*, it shows 0 count

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover I have updated regex. see update code and demo. Add character you want before `]`